# Multiplication of two deques of integers weird errors

Tags: c++, math, operator-overloading

this should be the final part of my integer class, and it seems to be very easy, and yet, something is wrong. is this code correct for multiplication using 2 deques?

```
    // 0x12345 = {0x01, 0x23, 0x45}

    integer operator*(integer rhs){
        // long multiplication
        unsigned int zeros = 0;
        std::deque <uint8_t> row;
        std::deque <std::deque <uint8_t> > temp;
        integer out = 0;
        for(std::deque <uint8_t>::reverse_iterator i = value.rbegin(); i != value.rend(); i++){
            row = std::deque <uint8_t>(zeros++, 0); // zeros on the right hand side
            uint8_t carry = 0;
            for(std::deque <uint8_t>::reverse_iterator j = rhs.value.rbegin(); j != rhs.value.rend(); j++){
                uint16_t prod = (uint16_t(*i) * uint16_t(*j)) + carry;// multiply through
                row.push_front((uint8_t) prod);
                carry = prod >> 8;
            }
            if (carry != 0)
                row.push_front(carry);
            out += integer(row);
        }
        return out;
    }
```

it is giving me `4931550625 ^ 2 -> 24248133972899962689`. assuming that the `operator+` is correct, which i seems to be, is there some other explanation of why this is wrong

edit: i updated the code according to wxffles, but i think i did it wrong, since im still getting `2424...`, and for `0x25 * 0x25` im getting `89 (decimal)`

edit2: the correct code is posted

Comment: so, ya, googlecalc says it should be 2.43201916 × 10e19, and your number is slightly different. I'm not running it, but... why do you do reverse iterator? that seems odd to me, I confess.

Comment: im going from the least significant values to the most significant values and yep that is the error. im off by that little

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the last carry.  Do you not need:

```
row.push_front(carry);
```

just before you add the row to out?

Comment: i added it at `uint16_t prod = (uint16_t(*i) * uint16_t(*j)) + carry;`, i think. default for carry is 0, so the least significant byte will have no carry

Comment: But on the final time through the inner loop, the last value of carry is never used.

Comment: @calccrypto I think your edit is wrong. I'd just do `if (carry != 0) row.push_front(carry);`

Comment: yay. thanks alot. i cant believe i did push_front(1). me and my silly fuzzy brain